# ExtJs determine visibility on form load

Tags: extjs, extjs3

In Extjs 3.4 I have a fairly large form that is being populated from an ajax call via `someForm.getForm().load({url: someplace, etc})` which is working flawlessly.  The problem I can't seem to get around though, is that there are several comboboxes and checkboxes that determine if another field is visible and `allowBlank`.

As per the answer on a similar question I have tried using the `actioncomplete` event on the form but the fields do not have values at that point.  I've also tried using the `success` event of the `load()` call but get the same issue.

Is there any other ways of getting this functionality from the `form.load()` call?

Edit - here is my `load` call:

```
var panel = Ext.getCmp('someFormID');
panel.getForm().load({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'ajax_get_request.aspx?id=' + id,
    success: function (form) {
        // This will error: object is null or undefined
        alert(form.findField('fieldID').getValue());
    }
});
```

I'm relatively new to Extjs so maybe I'm just missing something here...

Comment: Which object it complains about? `form` or return from `findField('fieldID')`?

Comment: It seems to me `'fieldID'` you're using might not be correct, so no field is found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why hooking into `success` callback of `Ext.form.BasicForm.load()` fails for you, but I can propose an alternative approach.

I usually use explicit `Ext.Ajax.request()` call to load data into `Ext.data.Record`. Then in `request()`'s `success` callback I load data into form using `Ext.form.BasicForm.loadRecord()`. If you need to act upon loaded values, you can do it in the same callback.

I do it this way, because I like to have original values from the server stored somewhere aside.

Comment: I figured the success callback would be the place to do this but maybe my code (see edit) isn't setup correctly?  I haven't used `Ext.data.Record` before so I'll look into that.

Comment: Well I'm not sure why but switching to using the name of the field instead of the ID seems to work correctly.  I'm really not sure why unless the form doesn't like having a variable appending to the ID when it's made (`id: 'somestring' + idVar,`)

Comment: That's right. Neither form nor any other ExtJS component likes that. ID is used in several places upon creation of component, and changing it afterwards will not propagate this change. Better leave `id`s alone once component is up and running.